# JPA Hibernate Typedef

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

In the project I am using JPA with Hibernate implementation. All the entities are annotation based and listed in persistence.xml.

All Entities are packaged into jar.

I need to define a typedef for few properties(in all the entities) which are a string to a enum type. In DB the Columns is varchar. How can i achieve this?

Can I achieve this by adding hbm.xml and hibernate-cfg.xml?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight from [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e6216):

> @org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef and
>   @org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs allows you to declare type
>   definitions. These annotations can be placed at the class or package
>   level. Note that these definitions are global for the session factory
>   (even when defined at the class level). If the type is used on a
>   single entity, you can place the definition on the entity itself.
>   Otherwise, it is recommended to place the definition at the package
>   level.

Comment: I have restriction..I cant edit the classes and repackage them into jar..That's why i mentioned at first they are packaged..

Comment: Noone said which package or which class.  And the documentation snippet goes out of its way to point out that no matter which package or class they are attached to, the typedef is global.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the classes but can change the hibernate config, I think you could change hibernate.mapping.precedence to be "hbm,class", and then add hbm files with all the information in the annotations for the relevant classes.  There is hbm syntax to specify a UserType or an EnumType.  You'd also have to define your UserType class if using that.

You might want to try this out on a test project before taking my word for it, I'm assuming it would work but I don't know for sure.

Copying all of the persistence information from annotations to hbm could be a pain, and would duplicate information.  Try if possible to find a way to add the annotations to the classes themselves.